# ASP VBScript Connection String to Access 2000 DB

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, database-connection

We have an old Access 2000 database that we need to pull data from and store it into a text file via a web interface that has to run every 20 minutes. I have spent hours and hours searching for a correct connection string without anything working.

I even used Dreamweaver's point-and-click solution and was able to get it to connect and pull data with a System DSN on my local machine, but it shows a 500 Internal Server Error when I upload it to the testing server (both the local and the testing server System DSNs have the same name). (For clarification to die-hard programmers, I am a developer and am using Dreamweaver because I have no idea what I'm doing with ASP.)

I created a System DSN on the testing server (win server 2008), but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know if it's something with the VB code I'm writing or an issue with the DSNs. Could I please get some help with this, my deadline for this is tomorrow morning! (If I don't meet the deadline, major systems in our business will not work!)

Dreamweaver Connection:

```
Dim MM_LocalDb_STRING
MM_LocalDb_STRING = "dsn=Db;"

Dim Students
Dim Students_cmd
Dim Students_numRows

Set Students_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
Students_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_LocalDb_STRING
Students_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Students" 
Students_cmd.Prepared = true
Students = Students_cmd.Execute
Students_numRows = 0
```

I have also seen various connection strings and have tried them with no success. Please help! (Thank you in advance.)

Comment: Have you looked at the Event Log on the testing server to see if it gives more information about the specific error?  If not, try accessing the page from the testing server if you can.  That should come back with a more specific error message than 500.

Comment: I looked at the Event Viewer, however the only thing on it relating to IIS is it crashed once when I was modifying its settings. The sysadmin rebooted it and verified my changes did not cause the crash, but I am still stuck with it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, try accessing the page locally on the test server.  I believe this should give you a more specific error than just the generic 500.

My thought, because this works on your dev machine, is that it's a permissions error.  You should make sure that the IUSR and, I think, LOCAL SERVICE accounts have read/write permissions to the database file.

Comment: Thanks, I am working on adding the permissions to the database now. I did access it locally on the test server, but it doesn't display anything other than the generic 500 - Internal server error page (I checked several other errors and they have detailed descriptions. I don't know if its a setting that the sys admin set, or what.)

I forgot to mention before that the database is on a different server, but as far as I know the sys admin set the permissions so that the web server can access the database server.